# Why is Kimihiro Watanuki plagued by youkai and ayakashi?

Tags: xxxholic

From the start of the series, Watanuki is tormented by them. Is there a reason why they "like" him so much?

- It's his smell?
- Some related parent (blood relationship)?
- Unlucky?

What is the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [first chapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yrqq.png) of the manga, Yuko tells him that spirits are attracted to his blood, eluding of his innate powers.

In [chapter 89](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgEyi.jpg), the Spider Queen mentions that several factions were fighting over his right eye, because if they make it their's (by eating it) it could multiply their spiritual power several dozen times.

It would seem that Watanuki is so powerful everyone wants a piece of him.